# Set selected value in selectbox angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an selectbox with options filled In It from my backend.

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-lg-4">Superkund</td>
    <td><select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item as item.namn for item in superkundOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)"></select></td>
</tr>

 $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/abb/getSuperkundData/' + $rootScope.abbForm).success(function(data) {
            $scope.superkundOptions = data;
        });
```

The problem I have Is that the first row Is an empty row, I want to replace that empty with an selected value. I have tried this:

```
$scope.selectedSupercustomer = "fish"
```

But that don't work. Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-init`. For example `ng-init` for the first item selected:

```
<select ng-init="selectedSupercustomer = superkundOptions[0]" ... ></select>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pqxo6rqx/)

Comment: @user500468 Your error is `superkundOptions[5]`. You try to select by id `5` but have to select by index of the necessary element in the `superkundOptions` array. If you want to select object with id = 5, your `ng-init` must be the following: `selectedSupercustomer = superkundOptions[0]` because `superkundOptions[0] = { id: 5, namn: 'Halmstad Bågen / Pilen' }`

Answer (score 1):

The select box works with references. That means, you have to set the model `$scope.selectedSupercustomer` to $scope.superkundOptions[ID/INDEX_OF_"fish"].

Comment: @AndréBauer: Like this: $scope.selectedSupercustomer = $scope.superkundOptions[0 + 'fish'];? Because that don't work.

Comment: it was meant like "find the id / index of the element with value "fish"

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at this example

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SomeController">
    <div ng-repeat="Person in People">
        <div class="listheader">{{Person.firstName}} {{Person.lastName}}</div>
        <div class="listitem" ng-repeat="Choice in Person.Choices">
            {{Choice.Name}}: 
            <select 
                ng-model="Choice.SelectedOption"                 
                ng-options="choice.Name for choice in Choice.Options track by choice.ID"></select>
            {{Choice.SelectedOption.ID}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.People = [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "Choices": [
            {
                "Name":"Dinner",
                "Options":[{Name:"Fish",ID:1}, {Name:"Chicken",ID:2}, {Name:"Beef",ID:3}],
                "SelectedOption":{Name:"Chicken",ID:2}
            },
            {
                "Name":"Lunch",
                "Options":[{Name:"Macaroni",ID:1}, {Name:"PB&J",ID:2}, {Name:"Fish",ID:3}],
                "SelectedOption":""
            }
        ],        
    }, {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }];
});
```

CSS:

```
body{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.listheader{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gFCzV/34/)

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: @user500468 couldnt add fiddle link without code so there is the link i hope this helps

Comment: @Bummi well done, your revision really made the answer look well : )